# Tool for snapping together 3d models

Tags: python, 3d, mesh, 3d-modelling

Is there any tool/software that I could use out of the box for snapping different 3d meshes together (even manually in an interactive mode but not really time consuming, considering that I would have to do that for a couple of hundred pieces)?

For example imagine that I have the following pieces:
[image]

Which they should be snapped as follows:
[image]

Then I've tried to use some existing tools/software like vedo, Meshlab, etc... for manually putting the pieces together but as you can see the output is not perfect plus it will take forever to find the best positioning (transformation matrices).
[image]

Thus, I was wondering if there is any tool/software that you are aware and that I could specify even manually (by marking, or with a scribble) which side of piece with which other side on another piece should be snapped and then I guess by adjusting some options would help to get a better positioning.

It is a bit tricky because not always the two boundaries match exactly as you can see below:
[image]

But if there is anything that you are aware and possibly would help me I would be grateful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We have worked a bit on this topic proposing a computer-assisted constraint-based methodology for virtual reassembly of Cultural Heritage (CH) artworks. Instead than focusing on automatic, unassisted reassembly, we targeted the scenarios where the reconstruction process is not be based on shape properties only but it is build over the experience and intuition of a CH expert.

G. Palmas, N. Pietroni, P. Cignoni and R. Scopigno, **"A computer-assisted constraint-based system for assembling fragmented objects,"** 2013 Digital Heritage International Congress (DigitalHeritage), 2013, pp. 529-536,
https://doi.org/10.1109/DigitalHeritage.2013.6743793

Unfortunately the tool we developed never reached a sufficient polishness level to be released in the public, but in the paper you can find hints on how to proceeds for this kind of problems.
P.S.
With 'released' I actually meant, released, maintained and supported in a reasonable way. As correctly indicated in the comments, for the brave ones, an unsupported prototype is available.

Comment: Interesting thanks. In the authors I can recognize some the guys that running meshlab, right? Do you know if I can have access even to the unpolished version of the tool. It might get on hand even in this stage.

Comment: Ok, I found a link to it here http://vcg.isti.cnr.it/~pietroni/reassembly/index.html. I will give it a try, in any case is a good reference. Thanks a lot.